# PostgreSQL : Selecting all values of a key in jsonb

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

This is the current code I'm using.

```
SELECT
(agent->>0)::jsonb->>'key',
(agent->>1)::jsonb->>'key'
FROM
table;
```

But it's possible that the `jsonb` column(`agent`) contains more than 2 sets of values. Is it possible to write a query without specifying indexing(not including 0,1 in query) and get the result as `array_agg` using just the key.

Sample jsonb :

```
[
  {
    "name" : "A",
    "key" : "KA"
  },
  {
    "name" : "B",
    "key" : "KB"
  }
]
```

My desired output be :

```
[KA, KB]
```

Comment: Post a sample of jsonb.

Comment: Posted a sample of jsonb @SalmanA, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Postgres 12 or later, you can use a JSON path query.

```
select jsonb_path_query_array(agent, '$.key')
from the_table;
```

Comment: This works perfectly on my local environment. However when I tried to deploy it for my company, this function wasn't available as the version there is 11.9. Are you aware of any alternative functions I can use for the same, thanks.

Comment: I asked a new question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69033703/equivalent-of-jsonb-path-query-array-in-postgresql-11

Answer (score -1):

Use jsonb_each function

```
SELECT jsonb_each(props) FROM users;
```