# Equivalent of jsonb_path_query_array in Postgresql-11

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-11

```
[
  {
    "name" : "A",
    "key" : "KA"
  },
  {
    "name" : "B",
    "key" : "KB"
  }
]
```

Given a column containing the above data,

I use `select jsonb_path_query_array(column, '$.key')` to get the output `[KA, KB]`

However this doesn't work in Postgres-11. Are there any alternatives for the same ?

Comment: Yeah, and that code worked when I was trying it out locally. However when I tried deploying it on my company's server, I found out that function wasn't available, since my company's currently using version 11.

Comment: Cool. Thanks mate, appreicate the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. This yields a Postgres array. Use `jsonb_agg` instead of `array_agg` if you need a JSON array.

```sql
select array_agg(j ->> 'key')
from jsonb_array_elements(column) t(j);
```

**Update**

```sql
select 
  (select array_agg(j ->> 'key') from jsonb_array_elements(column) t(j))
from the_table;
```

Comment: Thanks. Should I replace t with the table name.